# Affinity Designer Prevent Curve Overlap Cutout

Tags: pen-tool, affinity-designer

I'm making a shape in Affinity Designer using the pen tool, tweaking bezier curves, etc.

I have a shape that overlaps, meaning curves back and crosses over itself, so there's an intersection.  The default behavior for Affinity Designer is to create a subtractive effect, whereby the shape has no fill in the intersection.

I'd like the shape I've created to be filled in, even in the intersection.  How do I make Affinity do this?

Comment: Can you post an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably figured out a solution by now, but I thought I'd post here anyway.

[**From the manual:**](https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/pages/CurvesShapes/fillMode.html)

1. With the object selected, from the **Layer** menu, select an option from the **Fill Mode** sub-menu.
2. You are looking for the **Winding (Non-Zero)** option.